# Error: Device /dev/ttyACM0 is already locked

Tags: ros, turtlebot, hokuyo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I am a ROS beginner. I am doing SLAM of turtlebot 2 in the ubuntu 14.04, ros (indigo) personal computer environment.

I am doing this tutorial to add hokuyo.

> http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/hydro/Adding%20a%20Hokuyo%20laser%20to%20your%20Turtlebot

However, the hokuyo node does not start except the first time.

```
$ rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node
[ERROR] [1543820081.096981504]: Exception thrown while opening Hokuyo.
Device /dev/ttyACM0 is already locked. Try 'lsof | grep /dev/ttyACM0' to find other processes that currently have the port open. (in hokuyo::laser::open) You may find further details at http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Troubleshooting
```

and

```
$ lsof | grep /dev/ttyACM0
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /home/ujhou/.gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
hokuyo_no 29683          a    9uW     CHR              166,0       0t0      505 /dev/ttyACM0
hokuyo_no 29683  7681    a    9uW     CHR              166,0       0t0      505 /dev/ttyACM0
hokuyo_no 29683 29692    a    9uW     CHR              166,0       0t0      505 /dev/ttyACM0
hokuyo_no 29683 29693    a    9uW     CHR              166,0       0t0      505 /dev/ttyACM0
hokuyo_no 29683 29694    a    9uW     CHR              166,0       0t0      505 /dev/ttyACM0
hokuyo_no 29683 29699    a    9uW     CHR              166,0       0t0      505 /dev/ttyACM0
hokuyo_no 29683 29742    a    9uW     CHR              166,0       0t0      505 /dev/ttyACM0
```

What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309814/error:-device-/dev/ttyacm0-is-already-locked/) by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2018-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-03**:\

> hokuyo node does not start except the first time.

that "first time" is probably an indication of what is going on.

How are you stopping the node?

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2018-12-03**:
ctrl+c　or ✕ on terminal.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2018-12-03**:
you could run ps aux | grep hokuyo and see if there are some processes still running with hokuyo name. If it is the case kill them by running kill -9 pocess_id

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2018-12-04**:
thank you may friend.I can do it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It can be erased by this command.

```
kill -9 pocess_id
```

---

Originally posted by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) with karma: 50 on 2018-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0